# Understanding CPU pipeline stages vs. Instruction throughput

Tags: cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture, latency, instructions

I'm missing something fundamental re. CPU pipelines: at a basic level, why do instructions take differing numbers of clock cycles to complete and how come some instructions only take 1 cycle in a multi-stage CPU?

Besides the obvious of "different instructions require a different amount of work to complete", hear me out...

Consider an i7 with an approx 14 stage pipeline. That takes 14 clock cycles to complete a run-through. AFAIK, that should mean the entire pipeline has a latency of 14 clocks. Yet this isn't the case.

An XOR completes in 1 cycle and has a latency of 1 cycle, indicating it doesn't go through all 14 stages. BSR has a latency of 3 cycles, but a throughput of 1 per cycle. AAM has a latency of 20 cycles (more that the stage count) and a throughput of 8 (on an Ivy Bridge).

Some instructions cannot be issued every clock, yet take less than 14 clocks to complete.

I know about the multiple execution units. I don't understand how the length of instructions in terms of latency and throughput relate to the number of pipline stages.

Comment: What precisely do you mean when you say that XOR has a "latency of 1 cycle"? What is your source for that? That seems like a meaningless measurement.

Comment: Agner Fog's charts (http://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). It means that an XOR takes 1 clock cycle to execute, hence a latency of 1, whereas a BSR takes 3.

Comment: Did you read his explanation of what he means by latency? If so, I don't see why you would say that "XOR completes in 1 cycle and has a latency of 1 cycle, indicating it doesn't go through all 14 stages".

Comment: @IanC From reading your question and comments, I think you are confused between the stages of the pipeline and the latency of the functional units. They're not the same thing. Every (correct) instruction must pass through all the pipeline stages. Some stages have a fixed latency, others have a variable latency, e.g. the execute stage.

Comment: @Hayesti variable length execution stage... that is the missing puzzle piece. Thank you. So, to keep my examples, we could deduce BSR has a longer execute stage than say XOR.

Comment: @IanC yes, this is the typical behaviour. When you read optimisation manuals such as those from Intel or Agner Fog, the latency and throughput is referring to the functional units (execution stage).

Comment: I knew it was very simple in the end :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm missing something fundamental re. CPU pipelines: at a basic level, why do instructions take differing numbers of clock cycles to complete and how come some instructions only take 1 cycle in a multi-stage CPU?

Because what we're interested in is in speed between instructions, not the start to end time of a single instruction.

> Besides the obvious of "different instructions require a different amount of work to complete", hear me out...

Well that's the key answer to why different instructions have different latencies.

> Consider an i7 with an approx 14 stage pipeline. That takes 14 clock cycles to complete a run-through. AFAIK, that should mean the entire pipeline has a latency of 14 clocks. Yet this isn't the case.

That is correct, though that's not a particularly meaningful number. For example, why do we care how long it takes before the CPU is entirely done with an instruction? That has basically no effect.

> An XOR completes in 1 cycle and has a latency of 1 cycle, indicating it doesn't go through all 14 stages. BSR has a latency of 3 cycles, but a throughput of 1 per cycle. AAM has a latency of 20 cycles (more that the stage count) and a throughput of 8 (on an Ivy Bridge).

This is just a bunch of misunderstandings. An XOR introduces one cycle of latency into a dependency chain. That is, if I do 12 instructions that each modify the previous instruction's value and then add an XOR as the 13th instruction, it will take one cycle more. That's what the latency means.

> Some instructions cannot be issued every clock, yet take less than 14 clocks to complete.

Right. So?

> I know about the multiple execution units. I don't understand how the length of instructions in terms of latency and throughput relate to the number of pipline stages.

They don't. Why should there be any connection? Say there's 14 extra stages at the beginning of the pipeline. Why would that effect latency or throughput at all? It would just mean everything happens 14 clock cycles later, but still at the same rate. (Though likely it would impact the cost of a mispredicted branch and other things.)

Comment: Well, you understand how it works. Every example I can find shows a RISC (not CISC) pipeline where every equal-length instruction goes through all (typically 5) stages of the pipeline. Each stage performs a different function. Case in point: do XOR and BSR execute on all 14 (say) stages? If we picture the stages as workstations in a workshop, we would get the idea that a job goes from station to station and gets worked on, eventually retiring. But then why do some instructions cause > 1 cycle latency? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: @IanC At every point in the pipeline, the next instruction can't proceed to the next state of the pipeline unless all previous instructions on which that instruction depends have provided whatever that instruction needs to progress to that next stage. If two instructions in a row require a delay to the second instruction, the first instruction will introduce more than one cycle of latency. Consider, for example, a multiply followed by an increment of the result. At some point, the increment will have to wait for the multiply to make more progress.

Comment: @IanC Instructions frequently stall in the pipeline because the conditions needed for them to advance to the next step are not met. This includes needing to access information from main memory, needing execution resources used by other instructions, needing results from previous instructions, and so on.

Comment: What I'm still fuzzy on is how an instruction can have a latency of say 1 when it supposedly has to go through all 14 stages to execute. `add eax, $10` takes only 1 cycle, which is only 1 stage to execute. What happened to fetch, decode, convert to micro-op ... retire?

Comment: Then you still don't quite understand what latency means in this context. Latency is how many cycles longer a dependency chain would take if this instruction were added to its middle. So, for example, say we increment a register twice and that takes 17 cycles. Then we add a multiply by a constant between those two increments and now it takes 19 cycles. That means the multiply added 2 cycles of latency to the dependency chain. This basically means that at some point the second increment had to wait one extra cycle because the multiply hadn't progressed as far as the increment needed.

Comment: I get the principle. I'll diagram it out to make it more real. Thank you for your patience @David.

Answer (score 4):

I think what's missing from the existing answers is the existence of "bypass" or "forwarding" datapaths.  For simplicity, let's stick with the MIPS 5-stage pipeline.  Every instruction takes 5 cycles from birth to death -- fetch, decode, execute, memory, writeback.  So that's how long it takes to process a single instruction.

What you want to know is how long it takes for one instruction to hand off its result to a dependent instruction.  Say you have two consecutive ADD instructions, and there's a dependency through R1:

```
ADD R1, R2, R3
ADD R4, R1, R5
```

If there were no forwarding paths, we'd have to stall the second instruction for multiple cycles (2 or 3 depending on how writeback works), so that the first one could store its result into the register file before the second one reads that as input in the decode stage.

However, there are forwarding paths that allow valid results (but ones that are not yet written back) to be picked out of the pipeline.  So let's say the first ADD gets all its inputs from the register file in decode.  The second one will get R5 out of the register file, but it'll get R1 out of the pipeline register following the execute stage.  In other words, we're routing the output of the ALU back into its input one cycle later.

Out-of-order processors make ubiquitous use of forwarding.  They will have lots of different functional units that have lots of different latencies.  For instance, ADD and AND will typically take one cycle (TO DO THE MATH, putting aside all of the pipeline stages before and after), MUL will take like 4, floating point operations will take lots of cycles, memory access has variable latency (due to cache misses), etc.

By using forwarding, we can limit the critical path of an instruction to just the latencies of the execution units, while everything else (fetch, decode, retirement), it out of the critical path.  Instructions get decoded and dumped into instruction queues, awaiting their inputs to be produced by other executing instructions.  When an instruction's dependency is satisfied, then it can begin executing.

Let's consider this example

```
MUL R1,R5,R6
ADD R2,R1,R3
AND R7,R2,R8
```

I'm going to make an attempt at drawing a timeline that shows the flow of these instructions through the pipeline.

```
MUL  FDIXXXXWR
ADD   FDIIIIXWR
AND    FDIIIIXWR
```

Key:

```
F - Fetch
D - Decode
I - Instruction queue (IQ)
X - execute
W - writeback/forward/bypass
R - retire
```

So, as you see, the multiply instruction has a total lifetime of 9 cycles.  But there is overlap in execution of the MUL and the ADD, because the processor is pipelined.  When the ADD enters the IQ, it has to wait for its input (R1), and likewise so does the AND that is dependent on the ADD's result (R2).  What we care about is not how long the MUL lives in total but how long any dependent instruction has to wait.  That is its EFFECTIVE latency, which is 4 cycles.  As you can see, once the ADD executes, the dependent AND can execute on the next cycle, again due to forwarding.